# How do I call a batch of Laravel5 commands?

Tags: laravel-5, bus

I have a few complex commands that I split up into "sub commands" (Example following). As my site is multi-domain, I need the capability of customizing the sequence and composition of the sub commands to perform (so far I had this in a config under L4). With the migration to L5, I'm refactoring this functionality using the Command bus.

Example of a command sequence:
Site A:

```
1) AuthorizeCharge
2) DoSomethingA
3) DoSomethingB
4) Charge
```

Site B

```
 1) AuthorizeCharge
 2) DoSomethingA
 3) DoSomethingC
 4) DoSomethingD
 5) Charge
```

Each of these line items is a Command with it's Handler. This part is fairly clear to me (and works fine).

How can I dispatch this elegantly in my controller?

Here is what I already tried.

Fixed version (works)(in controller):

```
$return = $this->dispatch( new DoSomethingACommand($form));
$return[] = $this->dispatch( new DoSomethingBCommand($form));
```

Variable version (pseudo code):

someconfig.php

```
return [
   'DoSomethingACommand',
   'DoSomethingBCommand'
];
```

App\Namespace\Http\Controller\SomeController.php

```
...

//loop over all scenario commands
for ($j = 0; $j < count($commands); $j++) 
{
    //make the object which we need to act on
    $object = \App::make( $this->_namespace . '\\'. $commands[ $j ] );

    $return[] = $this->dispatchFrom( $object,  $form ); //Doesnt work
}
```

I'm a bit stuck on how to solve this. Any advice on how I could implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you just have a main command that then calls all the other sub-commands itself?

So have one major command called from your controller called `HandlePaymentProcessCommand`. Then inside that command you then call the sub-commands

```
 1) AuthorizeCharge
 2) DoSomethingA
 3) DoSomethingC
 4) DoSomethingD
 5) Charge
```

This way the sub-commands are all handled in one location (the main command) - and is easily configurable to be changed.

Comment: I don't see how this will help: HandlePaymentProcessCommand would have to be specific to this "Site 1/Domain" while I would have to create another HandlePaymentProcessCommand for "Site 2/Domain" as the content or sub commands would be slightly differently.

Comment: Just have one specific Command for each site on its controller. Then that command calls the specific sub-commands.

Comment: Ok, thanks - this suggestion works for me! I have a "site/domain" specific package anyway with client specific functionality and views/assets so I created the main command in the brand package and that one calls the individual "sub commands" from the core package.